# Cloud Dataflow Running really slow when reading/writing from Cloud Storage (GCS)

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

Since using the release of the latest build of Cloud Dataflow (0.4.150414) our jobs are running really slow when reading from cloud storage (GCS). After running for 20 minutes with 10 VMs we were only able to read in about 20 records when previously we could read in millions without issue.

It seems to be hanging, although no errors are being reported back to the console.

We received an email informing us that the latest build would be slower and that it could be countered by using more VMs but we got similar results with 50 VMs.

Here is the job id for reference:  2015-04-22_22_20_21-5463648738106751600

Instance: n1-standard-2
Region: us-central1-a

Comment: This is definitely not expected behavior. Let's clarify a couple of things: 1) are you able to quickly read those GCS files by regular "gsutil" commands? (just to make sure it's not a GCS issue) 2) can you try running the pipeline on a smaller subset of the data using DirectPipelineRunner, to check if it only occurs on VMs, or also locally?

Comment: Also you can try ssh'ing into one of your VMs and seeing what it's doing. One way to do that is to "ps aufx | grep java" to locate the Dataflow worker process, "sudo kill -3 $WORKER_PID" to force it to dump its stacktrace to its stdout, "sudo docker ps" to locate the taskrunner container in which that process runs (container ID is the left column), and then "sudo docker exec $CONTAINER_ID cat /dataflow/logs/taskrunner/harness/harness-stdout.log" to print its stdout, which should now have stack traces. (sorry, I know this is troublesome - we are working on improving the debugging experience)

Comment: I was able to read from the bucket using gsutil as well as run it locally using a smaller set of data without any issues. I will ssh onto the box now.

Comment: Hi Darren, were you able to extract any debug information by ssh'ing? It would be really valuable for us to fix the problem.

Comment: I SSHed in to one of the VMs and followed your steps but the directory /dataflow/logs does not exist.

Comment: See my workaround on the same issue - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29814922/dataflow-performance-issues/29885395#29885395

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had a similar issue. It is when the side-input is reading from a BigQuery table that has had its data streamed in, rather than bulk loaded. When we copy the table(s), and read from the copies instead everything works fine.

If your tables are streamed, try copying them and reading the copies instead. This is a workaround.

See: [Dataflow performance issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29814922/dataflow-performance-issues)

Answer (score 3):

Your job seems to be using side inputs to a `DoFn`. Since there has been a recent change in how Cloud Dataflow SDK for Java handles side inputs, it is likely that your performance issue is related to that. I'm reposting my answer from a related question.

---

The evidence seems to indicate that there is an issue with how your pipeline handles side inputs. Specifically, it's quite likely that side inputs may be getting re-read from BigQuery again and again, for every element of the main input. This is completely orthogonal to the changes to the type of virtual machines used by Dataflow workers, described below.

This is closely related to the changes made in the Dataflow SDK for Java, version 0.3.150326. In that release, we changed the side input API to apply per window. Calls to `sideInput()` now return values only in the specific window corresponding to the window of the main input element, and not the whole side input `PCollectionView`. Consequently, `sideInput()` can no longer be called from `startBundle` and `finishBundle` of a `DoFn` because the window is not yet known.

For example, the following code snippet has an issue that would cause re-reading side input for every input element.

```
@Override
public void processElement(ProcessContext c) throws Exception {
  Iterable<String> uniqueIds = c.sideInput(iterableView);

  for (String item : uniqueIds) {
    [...]
  }

  c.output([...]);
}
```

This code can be improved by caching the side input to a `List` member variable of the transform (assuming it fits into memory) during the first call to `processElement`, and use that cached `List` instead of the side input in subsequent calls.

This workaround should restore the performance you were seeing before, when side inputs could have been called from `startBundle`. Long-term, we will work on better caching for side inputs. (If this doesn't help fully resolve the issue, please reach out to us via email and share the relevant code snippets.)

---

Separately, there was, indeed, an update to the Cloud Dataflow Service around 4/9/15 that changed the default type of virtual machines used by Dataflow workers. Specifically, we reduced the default number of cores per worker because our benchmarks showed it as cost effective for typical jobs. This is *not* a slowdown in the Dataflow Service of any kind -- it just runs with less resources per worker, by default. Users are still given the options to override both the number of workers as well as the type of the virtual machine used by workers.