# Dataflow performance issues

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I'm aware that an update was made to the CDF service a few weeks ago (default worker type & attached PD were changed), and it was made clear that it would make batch jobs slower. However, the performance of our jobs has degraded beyond the point of them actually fulfilling our business needs.

For example, for one of our jobs in particular: it reads ~2.7 million rows from a table in BigQuery, has 6 side inputs (BQ tables), does some simple String transformations, and finally writes multiple outputs (3) to BigQuery. This used to take 5-6 minutes and now it takes anywhere between 15-20 mins - not matter how many VM's we chuck at it.

Is there anything we can do to get the speeds back up to what we used to see?

Here are some stats:

1. Reading from a BQ table with 2,744,897 rows (294MB)
2. 6 BQ side inputs
3. 3 multi-outputs to BQ, 2 of which are 2,744,897 and the other 1,500 rows
4. Running in zone asia-east1-b
5. Times below include worker pool spin up and tear down

10 VMs (n1-standard-2) 
**16 mins 5 sec**
2015-04-22_19_42_20-4740106543213058308

10 VMs (n1-standard-4) 
**17 min 11 sec**
2015-04-22_20_04_58-948224342106865432

10 VMs (n1-standard-1) 
**18 min 44 sec**
2015-04-22_19_42_20-4740106543213058308

20 VMs (n1-standard-2) 
**22 min 53 sec**
2015-04-22_21_26_53-18171886778433479315

50 VMs (n1-standard-2)
**17 min 26 sec**
2015-04-22_21_51_37-16026777746175810525

100 VMs (n1-standard-2)
**19 min 33 sec** 
2015-04-22_22_32_13-9727928405932256127

Comment: I took a look at the step execution logs of one of these jobs and it appears that the bulk of time (about 9 minutes out of 17) has been spent on importing the data already written by the step into BQ. We'll be looking into why this import process has become so slow.

Comment: is there a workaround I could use until you figure out why it's become so slow?

Comment: A teammate suggested that the slowness may be explained by a change in the way the new SDK treats side inputs - can you please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29718820/why-did-sideinput-method-move-from-context-to-processcontext-in-dataflow-beta and check if it's relevant to your job?

Comment: Also, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29685886/google-dataflow-write-to-bigquery-table-performance for tips on debugging BiqQuery export jobs - perhaps these stats will be useful for your performance debugging. Let me know if neither of these help.

Comment: @jkff WRT to the first link, we cache the side input on the first call to processElement(). We used to do it from startBundle(), but of course the API changed in on of the last releases, so we moved it to processElement().

Comment: @jkff WRT to the 2nd link, I'm confused now. In your first comment, you said that you checked the execution logs and that you'll be looking into why this has become so slow when writing to BQ. Our jobs used to run fine, so what something must have changed.

Comment: We are still looking into BigQuery slowness. Do you have a link to a job that ran fast? That would be helpful for me to compare its logs to the current run.

Comment: Update: I found some room for optimization (eg. BQ import tasks for the output of a single map step were not being parallelized) which will be a big win, but it's still unclear why the import itself got so slow. Can you try "bq show -j dataflow_job_10405710510286137087" (it's one of the BQ import jobs executed as part of your pipeline) to see if there's any interesting performance statistics there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We tracked down the issue. It is when the side-input is reading from a BigQuery table that has had its data streamed in, rather than bulk loaded. When we copy the table(s), and read from the copies instead everything works fine.

However, this is just a workaround. Dataflow should be able to handle streamed tables in BigQuery as side-inputs.

Answer (score 4):

The evidence seems to indicate that there is an issue with how your pipeline handles side inputs. Specifically, it's quite likely that side inputs may be getting re-read from BigQuery again and again, for every element of the main input. This is completely orthogonal to the changes to the type of virtual machines used by Dataflow workers, described below.

This is closely related to the changes made in the Dataflow SDK for Java, version 0.3.150326. In that release, we changed the side input API to apply per window. Calls to `sideInput()` now return values only in the specific window corresponding to the window of the main input element, and not the whole side input `PCollectionView`. Consequently, `sideInput()` can no longer be called from `startBundle` and `finishBundle` of a `DoFn` because the window is not yet known.

For example, the following code snippet has an issue that would cause re-reading side input for every input element.

```
@Override
public void processElement(ProcessContext c) throws Exception {
  Iterable<String> uniqueIds = c.sideInput(iterableView);

  for (String item : uniqueIds) {
    [...]
  }

  c.output([...]);
}
```

This code can be improved by caching the side input to a `List` member variable of the transform (assuming it fits into memory) during the first call to `processElement`, and use that cached `List` instead of the side input in subsequent calls.

This workaround should restore the performance you were seeing before, when side inputs could have been called from `startBundle`. Long-term, we will work on better caching for side inputs. (If this doesn't help fully resolve the issue, please reach out to us via email and share the relevant code snippets.)

---

Separately, there was, indeed, an update to the Cloud Dataflow Service around 4/9/15 that changed the default type of virtual machines used by Dataflow workers. Specifically, we reduced the default number of cores per worker because our benchmarks showed it as cost effective for typical jobs. This is *not* a slowdown in the Dataflow Service of any kind -- it just runs with less resources per worker, by default. Users are still given the options to override both the number of workers as well as the type of the virtual machine used by workers.

Comment: That's what we already do - we read the side input once in processElement(), and cache the results in a internal variable (a HashMap in our case), and use that for each subsequent call to processElement(). Prior to the lastest release, this was all working fine.

Comment: No, a new instance of a `ParDo` is not created for each call to `processElement()`. That would defeat the purpose of a bundle. However, your empirical evidence seems to suggest something along those lines. I'm going to reach out to you separately, and let's post an answer when we get to the bottom of this.